# PrepareStatement hangs on the executeUpdate function

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Got a problem with my add function to my database. The following code hangs on the ExecuteUpdate statement, it doens't throw an exception so I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
public static boolean addUser(User userToAdd) throws Exception {
    boolean isAdded = false;

    if (checkConnection()) {
        try {
            if (isUnique(userToAdd.getIdCardNumber())) {
                PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users SET "
                        + "idCardNr = ?,nationality = ?,name = ?,"
                        + "address = ?,photo = ?,status = ?,gender = ?,"
                        + "nationalNr = ?,birthDate = ?,birthPlace = ?,"
                        + "created = ?, country = ?");

                pstmt.setString(1, userToAdd.getIdCardNumber());
                pstmt.setString(2, userToAdd.getNationality());
                pstmt.setString(3, userToAdd.getFullName());
                pstmt.setString(4, userToAdd.getAddress());
                pstmt.setString(5, userToAdd.getPhotoPath());
                pstmt.setString(6, userToAdd.getStatus());
                pstmt.setString(7, userToAdd.getGender());
                pstmt.setString(8, userToAdd.getRegisterNumber());
                pstmt.setString(9, userToAdd.getBirthday());
                pstmt.setString(10, userToAdd.getBirthPlace());
                java.sql.Timestamp current = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                userToAdd.setCreated(current);
                pstmt.setTimestamp(11, userToAdd.getCreated());
                pstmt.setString(12, userToAdd.getCountry());


                int rowsAffected;
                try {
                   rowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    throw new Exception("Exception while executing update: " + e.getMessage());
                }


                if (rowsAffected != 0) {
                    isAdded = true;
                    pstmt.close();
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println("User already in database");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return isAdded;
}
```

Can someone help me how to debug this?

Comment: The connection used for the insert and the connection used for the `isUnique` method are the same, right? (want to exclude some blocking between your own code). Also: did you try to execute the insert manually from some SQL client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is malformed, you are trying to INSERT using the syntax for UPDATE.

This is how a standard INSERT looks

```
INSERT INTO users (idCardNr,nationality,name,address,photo,status,gender,nationalNr,birthDate,birthPlace,created,country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

It's always a good idea to test your SQL manually before you put it into your code.

Comment: Thanks, working together with a group for a groupsproject. I didn't check the query, was trying with the execute. Thanks realy, it is solved.

Comment: I doubt this was the problem. The query is valid according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html. And it wouldn't hang if it was a syntax problem. It would throw an exception. The statement probably waited for a lock to be released (forgot to commit some update for example)

Comment: @JBNizet Indeed, I was not aware that mysql allowed that.

Comment: +1 @JBNizet. Also in case anyone else runs across this, My Java code was fine, but I had SQL Devloper open to inspect the result at the same time, and IT was causing the lock! FYI.

Comment: @JBNizet can you expand on the SQL Developer issue? I am facing same issue as you, do I need to completely close SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

- Had the same problem.
- updates/inserts hanged 96% of the time with no apparent reason.
- Setup: Old java Virtual Machine: JRockit 1.5 + Weblogic 10.0 on Windows
- Hanged up on preparedStatement.execute() and even crashed the entire JVM Twice!

## Cause(JVM Vendor not that important)

- The JVM Timezone data was outdated, messed up the date serialization when Date parameters where present.
- The tzdata was back from 2006! we are 2013 right now!

## Solution

- Use your **TimeZone Updater Tool** from your JDK or support page. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) for JRockit JDK or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/tzupdate.html) for Oracle JDK.
- Restart your Application.